# Why do we say "challenge accepted" instead of "challenge is accepted"?

Tags: passive-voice

I have never heard someone say "challenge is accepted" however it sounds more formal to me than "challenge accepted"

I am not a native speaker by the way.

let me know what do you think , thanks in advance.

Comment: "Challenge accepted" is just a shorthand way of saying "the challenge is accepted." Perhaps it sounds bolder and more aggressive, harkening back to the days when a "challenge" was an invitation to combat or a duel.

Comment: Likewise, military, police, etc, say "message understood" on the radio rather than "your message has been understood" for reasons of efficiency and brevity.